# Can't bind an Ember Dropdown to a controller property

Tags: ember.js

I don't understand what I am missing in order to bind the values from my controller to the template. The examples I've looked at seem to look like my code but I get a dropdown without any items in it.
Can anyone show me the mistake I've made? The site I'm working on is Ember v1.13.0 and I can't upgrade it at this moment.

I have a controller called "download.js" that looks like this

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Controller .extend({

   selectedMonth: null,

    monthValues: function() {
    return [
      {id: 1, name: "January"},
      {id: 2, name: "February"},
      {id: 3, name: "March"},
      {id: 4, name: "April"},
      {id: 5, name: "May"},
      {id: 6, name: "June"},
      {id: 7, name: "July"},
      {id: 8, name: "August"},
      {id: 9, name: "September"},
      {id: 10, name: "October"},
      {id: 11, name: "November"},
      {id: 12, name: "December"}
    ];
  }.property()

});
```

I have a template called "download.hbs" that looks like this.

```
<div class="ibox-content">
    <form>
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4" style="margin-top: 10px">
              {{view "select"
                     id="months"
                     content=monthValues
                     selection=selectedMonth
                     optionValuePath="content.id"
                     optionLabelPath="content.name"
                     prompt="Select month..." }}
          </div>
      </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Yours code is working. look at this [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/2e20c81a0423b9ad17ed7453b828a7bf?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C) so possible issue might be path of controller, it should be `app/controllers/download.js` and path of template would be `app/templates/download.hbs`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me. It led to me finding the spelling mistake in the file name of the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a spelling mistake in the name of my controller.
It started working as soon as I fixed it.